# Dropzone js rejects last file added

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js to upload a set of images. I have my dropzone set up so that the queue of file uploads is only processed after at least 10 files have been added to it like this:

```
var fileCount = 0;

dz.on("addedfile", function(file){
    fileCount++;

    if(fileCount >= 10){
        dz.processQueue();
        fileCount = 0;
    }
});
```

However, for some reason only 9 of the files are accepted and one of them is rejected. I have tried this with a different number of files (e.g. 5 total files. 4 get accepted and 1 is rejected). Is there any reason why this happens?

My dropzone is setup with the following options:

```
var dz = new Dropzone('div#upload-container', {
    url: "./testupload.php",
    dictDefaultMessage: "Click or Drop Files Here",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 10000,
    maxFiles: 10000,
    acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg,image/JPG,image/JPEG,image/PNG",
    maxFilesize: 5,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false
});
```

I have also tried doing the following:

```
dz.on("addedfile", function(file){
    if(dz.getQueuedFiles().length >= 10){
        dz.processQueue();
    }
});
```

but I run into the same issue.

Comment: How are you testing it? When I copy your code and run it myself, I'm not getting that the last file is rejected, but rather it just doesn't upload, and I understand why that is - the "addedfile" event has occurred but the file hasn't been added to the queue yet, so it doesn't get uploaded.

Comment: I `console.log(dz.getAcceptedFiles().length)` and `console.log(dz.getRejectedFiles().length)` after I check the `fileCount` variable, and this tells that one of my N files gets rejected.